# Flutter web App fails to deploy on cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, flutter-web, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to follow example at [How to deploy Flutter WebApp using Google Cloud Run](https://medium.com/tide-engineering-team/deploy-flutter-webapp-using-gcp-cloud-run-4511c3d87e92) and it says

> Create a Dockerfile in the root folder; this file configures the
> Docker image and containerizes the app. Copy the following content
> into your Dockerfile

that I created as well as server.sh in server folder ,

When I run

gcloud builds submit — tag gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{YOUR-IMAGE-NAME}:$tag .

```
 C:\projects\myproject11>gcloud builds submit — tag gcr.io/myproject11/xyz:1.0
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) unrecognized arguments:
  tag
  gcr.io/myproject11/xyz:1.0
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

C:\projects\myproject11>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the error is due to long dash tag  in the command you are trying to run. You need to add the `--` before `tag` to indicate that it's a flag.you can check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit) for examples

As mentioned [here](https://cheerful-walter.medium.com/the-code-block-changes-dash-dash-tag-to-long-dash-tag-in-below-command-so-error-when-copy-and-29b2e2a33a2), looks like you are also facing the same issue as you  following the example in medium .

> The code block changes “dash dash tag” to “long dash tag” in Medium
> code block formatting.It should be :
>
> ```
> gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/pdf-service
> ```